# Working with multiple files across multiple plans in drake

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I am attempting to use the `drake` R package to process multiple file inputs across multiple plans, so I can build up my targets iteratively, testing what works at each stage. Below is a trivial reprex showing what I am trying to accomplish. The official docs show how to do this type of thing *within* a single plan, but my difficulty is I want to do this *across* multiple plans.

I cannot work out what the transform should be to get the correct input names (targets from `read_in_plan`) into the `munge_plan`

```r
library(drake)
dplyr_version_dep = pkg_description = utils::packageDescription('dplyr')

munge_data = function(input){
  message("I did something!")
}

file_inputs = c("file1.csv", "file2.csv")

# get my data in
read_in_plan = drake_plan(
  # make the plan dependent on changes to dplyr
  pkg = utils::packageDescription('dplyr'),
  data = target(
    read.csv(input),
    transform = map(input = !!file_inputs)
  )
)

read_in_plan
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   target         command                           
#>   <chr>          <expr>                            
#> 1 pkg            utils::packageDescription("dplyr")
#> 2 data_file1.csv read.csv("file1.csv")             
#> 3 data_file2.csv read.csv("file2.csv")

# now do something to each of those targets
munge_plan = drake_plan(
  munged = munge_data(data_file1.csv)
)

munge_plan
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   target command                   
#>   <chr>  <expr>                    
#> 1 munged munge_data(data_file1.csv)

# but really I want to do munge data on all of the
# data_file1.csv
# data_file2.csv

# munge_data_proper = drake_plan(
#   munged = target(
#     # some kind of transform here
#   )
# )

full_plan = bind_plans(read_in_plan,
                       munge_plan)
# make(full_plan)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformations are designed to all happen inside a single call to `drake_plan()`, so it is difficult to split up the `data_*` targets and the `munged_*` targets below into different plans.

```r
library(drake)
dplyr_version_dep = pkg_description = utils::packageDescription('dplyr')

munge_data = function(input){
    message("I did something!")
}

file_inputs <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv")

plan <- drake_plan(
    pkg = target(
        dplyr_version_dep,
        # Triggers are always checked even though commands do not always run:
        trigger = trigger(change = utils::packageDescription("dplyr"))
    ),
    data = target(
        read.csv(input),
        transform = map(input = !!file_inputs, .id = FALSE)
    ),
    # Borrow from the previous transform:
    munged = target(
        munge_data(data),
        transform = map(data)
    )
)

drake_plan_source(plan)
#> drake_plan(
#>   pkg = target(
#>     command = dplyr_version_dep,
#>     trigger = trigger(
#>       change = utils::packageDescription("dplyr")
#>     )
#>   ),
#>   data = read.csv("file1.csv"),
#>   data_2 = read.csv("file2.csv"),
#>   munged_data = munge_data(data),
#>   munged_data_2 = munge_data(data_2)
#> )
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For you, one hack is to grab information from `drake_plan(trace = TRUE)`. Brittle, but useful in this small example.

```r
library(drake)
dplyr_version_dep = pkg_description = utils::packageDescription('dplyr')

munge_data = function(input){
    message("I did something!")
}

file_inputs <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv")

plan1 <- drake_plan(
    pkg = target(
        dplyr_version_dep,
        # Triggers are always checked even though commands do not always run:
        trigger = trigger(change = utils::packageDescription("dplyr"))
    ),
    data = target(
        read.csv(input),
        transform = map(input = !!file_inputs, .id = FALSE)
    ),
    trace = TRUE
)

plan1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   target command         trigger                           input      data 
#>   <chr>  <expr>          <expr>                            <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 pkg    dplyr_version_… trigger(change = utils::packageD… <NA>       <NA> 
#> 2 data   read.csv("file… NA                              … "\"file1.… data 
#> 3 data_2 read.csv("file… NA                              … "\"file2.… data…

plan1$input
#> [1] NA              "\"file1.csv\"" "\"file2.csv\""

plan1$data
#> [1] NA       "data"   "data_2"

# Put together the data manually for the next transformation.
library(magrittr)
data <- plan1$data %>%
  na.omit() %>%
    unique() %>%
    rlang::syms()

str(data)
#> List of 2
#>  $ : symbol data
#>  $ : symbol data_2

plan2 <- drake_plan(
    munged = target(
        munge_data(d),
        transform = map(d = !!data) # !! is key
    )
)

plan2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   target        command           
#>   <chr>         <expr>            
#> 1 munged_data   munge_data(data)  
#> 2 munged_data_2 munge_data(data_2)

full_plan <- bind_plans(dplyr::select(plan1, target, command), plan2)

full_plan
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   target        command              
#>   <chr>         <expr>               
#> 1 pkg           dplyr_version_dep    
#> 2 data          read.csv("file1.csv")
#> 3 data_2        read.csv("file2.csv")
#> 4 munged_data   munge_data(data)     
#> 5 munged_data_2 munge_data(data_2)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: OK, well, I don't like brittleness, so will probably avoid the hack.

Comment: So, what really matters for `drake` are the targets, and changes to the targets or their sources, so if I have to keep building up an individual plan with transforms, then it shouldn't be a big deal correct?

Also, it turns out that the caching for these objects results in insane memory requirements, so I may have to use intermediate files instead, which should be a *little* more amenable to transforms **between** plans.

Comment: Well, it's brittle in the sense that may not generalize to all workflows. Some columns in the trace are half-formed target names and not true targets, but others are okay. It's hard to know which unless you check particular cases.

Comment: And yes, I recommend that you gradually add new targets to an old plan as you increase the size and scope of your workflow. It is good practice to, say, start with a small plan, run make(), check the results, add some more targets, run make() again,  check the new results, add more targets, and so on.

Comment: Since you raised the point, let's talk about memory. By default, make() keeps all the targets in memory until the very end, which prioritizes speed over memory. You can change this behavior with the `memory_strategy` and `garbage_collection` arguments of `make()`. If you do not see an improvement, please post a new issue with a reprex: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues. `drake`'s resource requirements need to be sane.